# How do I compare HTML text with strings out of an array in an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, indexof

The user in this quiz can choose a name:

```
<p>Wie is jouw allergrootste vijand</p>
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Loki" class="vijand"> Loki
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Joker" class="vijand"> Joker
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Two Face" class="vijand"> Two Face
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Red Skull" class="vijand"> Red Skull
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Thanos" class="vijand"> Thanos
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Killmonger" class="vijand"> Killmonger
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Black Adam" class="vijand"> Black Adam
<input type="radio" name="vijand" value="Hela" class="vijand"> Hela
```

I want to compare this with the names inside an array. My idea was to use the index numbers to compare this so I tried to use `.indexOf()` but his is not working.

```
function vijand(){
    var vijanden = ['Loki', 'Joker', 'Two Face', 'Red Skull', 'Thanos', 'Killmonger', 'Black Adam', 'Hela'];
    var keuze = document.getElementsByClassName('vijand').value;
    var vijandNummer;

    //De eerste 4 uit de array
    if ( keuze === vijanden.indexOf(0,1,2,3)) {
        vijandNummer = 1;
    }    
    else if (keuze === vijanden.indexOf(4,5,6,7) ) {
        vijandNummer = 0;
    }

    return vijandNummer;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read the documentation on indexOf() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

```
function vijand(){
    var vijanden = ['Loki', 'Joker', 'Two Face', 'Red Skull', 'Thanos', 'Killmonger', 'Black Adam', 'Hela'];
    var vijandNummer;

    var vijandenValue = document.querySelector('input[name=vijand][checked]').value;

    if(['Loki', 'Joker', 'Two Face', 'Red Skull'].indexOf(vijandValue) !== -1) {
        vijandNummer = 1
    }

    if(['Thanos', 'Killmonger', 'Black Adam', 'Hela'].indexOf(vijandValue) !== -1) {
        vijandNummer = 0
    }

    return vijandNummer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `indexOf` in a wrong way. You want:

```
var index = vijanden.indexOf(keuze); // for keuze = 'Hela', index = 7
```

Then:

```
vijandNummer = index < 4 ? 1 : 0;
```

Assuming, by your code, that `vijandNummer` must be 1 if selected any of the first four heroes and 0 otherwise.